# Viewbag "Value cannot be null", but it's not null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

So I'm populating a @Html.DisplayText with a value from viewbag but I get a ArgumentNullException when the value exists.

This is the action method

```
public ActionResult Index(DateTime? fechaInicio, DateTime? fechafin, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    if (!fechaInicio.HasValue || !fechafin.HasValue) return View();
    if (searchString == null)
        searchString = currentFilter;
    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
    ViewBag.CurrentFechaInicio = fechaInicio;
    ViewBag.CurrentFechaFin = fechafin;
    var param = new Parametros()
    {
        FechaInicio = fechaInicio.Value,
        FechaFin = fechafin.Value
    };
    IEnumerable<Registro> registros = _registroRepository.ObtenerRegistros(param);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        registros = registros.Where(s => s.Patente.Contains(searchString));
    }
    if (!registros.Any())
        return View("SinResultados");
    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    return View("List",registros.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

[image]

Tried changing

```
ViewBag.CurrentFechaInicio = fechaInicio;
```

to

```
ViewBag.CurrentFechaInicio = fechaInicio.Value;
```

but nothing changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is: it is not a string but a DateTime, so `as string` returns `null`

You'll need the

```
.ToString()
```

method.

The `as` keyword "[is like a cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as)"

> Note that the as operator performs only reference conversions, nullable conversions, and boxing conversions. The as operator can't perform other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, which should instead be performed by using cast expressions.

Comment: yes, i just need to wait 8 more minutes to accept the answer.